# Why does heat engine need to reject energy to environment?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, efficient-energy-use

The most efficient thermodynamics cycle is the Carnot cycle, it involves

1/ Receiving heat from hot source, expanding and doing work on the surround

2/ Receiving work from environment, being compressed and rejecting heat to surround.

So the efficient is limited by $n = \frac{(T_H - T_C)}{T_H}$ where $T_H$ and $T_C$ are absolute temperature of hot and could source.

In the cycle, there is a step where heat engine receiving work from surround, thus lower the total work it can do. The question is, why does heat engine need that, why just ignore that, e.g. don't compress the gas so don't waste that work?

For example, let say we burn oil to heat air, the air is expanded and turn a turbine. We don't compress gas so any heat that air received will do work on the turbine.

By doing so, all received heat will be transfer to work, isn't it?

Why does every heat engine need to re compress gas to do the negative work on the environment?

Comment: A turbine extracts energy from a pressure difference and it requires the inlet working fluid to be pressurized above the outlet pressure.

Comment: Doesn't heated air having higher pressure than cool air? So there is the pressure gradient, which will turn the turbine. You can see the pressure as the hot air is lifted up. If hot air has the same pressure as cool air, there is no balloon

Comment: The only reason why there is a higher pressure inside a turbine than on the outside is because of the compressor on the inlet side. If you take the compressor out, air won't flow trough the turbine, at all. What would make it? A turbine is a compressor followed by a combustion chamber followed by the expansion turbine, which is connected trough a shaft to the compressor. Take the compressor out and the entire machine stops working.

Comment: At first, the heated air at the inlet has higher pressure than cool air at the other side, and air runs through the turbine. While runs through the turbine, some of the energy of air is extracted and cooled, keeping the outlet cooler than the inlet, which is the gradient pressure.

Comment: The air at the inlet of a turbine is room temperature. It then goes trough a compressor, then it gets heated. Please take a look at how a turbine actually works.

Comment: I know how turbine works, the above comment said about the case when heated air by oil run through turbine. You said there is no pressure gradient when air is heated (which is clearly wrong, and you dare to answer physics question???). I said heated air has higher pressure and will run through turbine, because there is a pressure gradient between hot air and cool air. When hot air run through turbine, it is cooled because energy is extracted.

Comment: When you heat air, it expands against the ambient pressure, but the pressure stays the same. I can only suggest that you think this trough once more and you read up on the design of turbines and their thermodynamics.

Comment: @user2174870 If you remove the compressor, the hot air will rather go out the front of the turbine instead of through it.

Answer (score 4):

1)You must have clear on your mind that engines do not work on any thermodynamic cycle.Per example, a diesel engine "consumes" fuel and air and expels an equal amount of exhaust gas. Nothing returns to the beginning. Even a rankine cycle that i saw on comments produces superheated steam and the boiler receives cold water and it is certainly not the same

2)Engines have cooling systems and this is a practical consideration. This is the way to protect the metals or the materials that compose the engine.Engines either reject heat or melt.Nothing prevents from heating an engine instead of cooling it, giving entropy instead of rejecting it except the strength of materials

3)I also want to ask you how an engine that does work ( changes volume ) will expand the working substance (air,gas,steam, anything) without compressing it first.

Comment: You don't understand difference between the rejecting heat in a thermodynamic cycle and the cooling system. You just burn oil to heat air, and hot air will expand (change volume - do work), you don't need any compressor in this process.

Comment: @user2174870. You change a compressor for a boiler. Common sense and thermodynamics assure that you do not gain anything

Comment: @user2174870 Ok, do not cool the air. After some time this place will be so hot that density of air will change and your turbine will stop moving etc etc

Comment: The turbine will extract the energy from the hot air and cool it.

Comment: @user2174870 I mean the place where you will heat the air

Comment: OK, I know what you meant, but that is the point of cold source. Do it in open air and you will have infinite cool air. Heat air, hot air will go up, let it run through a turbine vertically to extract energy, and you take cool air from below, there is an infinite amount of cool air, why heat engine needs to compress and cool it? Now do you understand the point in my question?

Comment: @user2174870 I answered you at the last paragraph of my answer. If you have a turbine, you also a need a nozzle.

Answer (score 3):

As asserted by [knzhou](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/83398/knzhou) in his [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/248606/36790), heat engines work in cycle and that's why it has to dump entropy before starting a new cycle (and that is the final nail in the coffin of *perpetual motion of second kind*).

---

Let $\delta Q_\textrm{H}$ be the amount of thermal energy that is taken up by the system from the hot reservoir. Therefore, entropy change of the system and reservoir respectively:

$$\mathrm dS_\mathrm{sys}= \frac{\delta Q_\textrm{H}}{T_\mathrm{sys_H}} \\ \mathrm dS_\mathrm{hot \,res}= \frac{-\delta Q_\textrm{H}}{T_\textrm{H}}$$

Now, since, it operates in a cycle, this must mean it has to dump that extra entropy $\mathrm dS_\mathrm{sys}$ as the net change in entropy after a cycle is zero viz. $$\Delta S_\textrm{cycle,sys}= 0\;.$$

In order to achieve this, the system dumps this *extra* gained entropy by giving off thermal energy to the cold surroundings or *cold reservoir*.

The entropy change of the system and entropy change of the cold reservoir respectively as: $$\mathrm dS_\mathrm{sys}= \frac{-\delta Q_\textrm{C}}{T_\mathrm{sys_C} }\\ \mathrm dS_\mathrm{cold \,res}= \frac{\delta Q_\textrm{C}}{T_\textrm{C}} \;.$$

Now, $\Delta S_\textrm{cyc,sys}= 0$ means

\begin{align}\mathrm dS_\textrm{universe}&\ge 0\\ \implies   \mathrm dS_\textrm{sys} + \mathrm dS_\textrm{res} &\ge 0\\\implies  \underbrace{\left(\frac{\delta Q_\textrm{H}}{T_\mathrm{sys_H}}+ \frac{-\delta Q_\textrm{C}}{T_\mathrm{sys_C} }\right)}_0 + \frac{-\delta Q_\mathrm{H}}{T_\textrm{H}}+\frac{\delta Q_\textrm{C}}{T_\textrm C}&\ge 0\\ \implies \frac{Q_\textrm C}{Q_\textrm{H}}& \ge \frac{T_\textrm C}{T_\textrm H}\tag{1}\end{align}

Now, $$W= Q_\textrm H- Q_\textrm C$$ and efficiency $$e\equiv \frac{\textrm{work}}{\textrm{heat absorbed}}= \frac{Q_\textrm H-Q_\textrm C}{Q_\textrm H}\tag 2$$

Using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$e\le 1- \frac{T_\textrm C}{T_\textrm H}$$

---

So, how does the last result come?

It came because of the second law and that **the change in entropy(a *state variable*) of the system/engine is zero over a thermodynamic cycle**.

Comment: What do you say about the example above? Burn oil, heat air, air expand and go up, let air run through a turbine vertically to extract energy, and take cool air from below. This cycle runs till oil runs out, and there is no need to dump any thing from heated air.

Comment: @user2174870: Have you checked what you asked: _Why does heat engine need to reject energy to environment_? This is the answer. I'm checking though your later query.....

Comment: Your elegant answer is irrelevant because the user botched up his question Besides this, i do not know anything in earth that works on a cycle except the refrigerator.

Comment: an engine perhaps?

Comment: @veronika: So, according to you, engines  don't work in cycle?

Comment: @Skyler: Do you want to tell me something?

Comment: @MAFIA36790. Yes, it is not a thermodynamic cycle. And the thermodynamic efficiency is of very relative importance.

Comment: @veronika: Dear Veronika, can you tell me what you meant by 'relative importance'?

Comment: @MAFIA36790. An engineer knows only the calorific value of fuel and the indicated pressure of the engine. the calorific value is the gibbs free energy difference between the reactants (fuel and air ) and the products. What you give is what you get. An engine and a heating coil have the same efficiency: 100 percent. Of course, the indicated pressure is the way to compare different engines. An engine with higher indicated pressure can burn more. That is why bigger engines are more "efficient"

Comment: @veronika: So, heat engines have 100% efficiency?

Comment: @MAFIA36790 Combustion is a chemical reaction and if a chemical reaction has efficiency then my car also has

Comment: I think maybe you should rigorously define efficiency as you are using it since the usual physical definition diverges from your usage

Answer (score 2):

Heat engines are supposed to be cyclic, so that after one cycle, the state of the engine itself is exactly where it started. If you don't expel heat, you can only get back to the initial state by undoing whatever you just did, so the cycle does zero net work. Expelling heat lets you get a positive area in your PV curve.

This argument doesn't apply to burning oil, because that's not a cyclic process.

Comment: A steam turbine is described by a Rankine cycle and gas turbines work in a Brayton cycle.

Comment: So did you mean that burning oil will surpass Carnot cycle's efficiency?

Comment: The positive area of a PV curve and the area of a TS diagram unfortunately for all engineers are irrelevant for every irreversible process

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume a gas at $300~\mathrm K$ (ambient)and volume $100~\mathit l$ heating it upto $600~\mathrm K$ will raise the temperature of gas to $600~\mathrm K$ and will cause it to expand twice its volume to $200~\mathit l$ (will push the piston or turbine).

But it all stops at this point ..... now you have a raised piston and gas at $600~\mathrm K$ now either you keep the gas or reject it to atmosphere, you will lose the heat to the surrounding at $300~\mathrm K$ because the gas cannot expand more and it has already been heated to $600~\mathrm K$.

Now we try to cool that air so we can extract *more* work and then we realise that cooling is actually a fancy word used for *rejecting heat*. And any rejection brings our engine efficiency down.